# Empirical logit transformation on percentage data

Tags: regression, data-transformation, proportion, logit

I have already used the logit transform on my outcome variables (which are displayed in percentages). However, this obviously gives me -INF values and since my data includes a lot of zeros in some instances, this makes it hard to analyse.

I have now tried an empirical logit transform, adding the smallest non-zero promotion to the numerator and denominator of my variables to remove the -INF values (as suggested in http://www.esajournals.org/doi/abs/10.1890/10-0340.1).

However, now my data are very non-normal again. I have tried experimenting with error terms to add to the logit transform but since have had no luck.

Is there any way I can find a value to add to my transformation to ensure normality?

Comment: A worthy option for your consideration is a generalized linear model.  Please search our site for threads on GLMs.  If you still want to transform the response, then search for threads about transformations, logarithms, and regression: many of them explicitly discuss whether and how to add a "start value" to the data before re-expressing them.

Comment: If your outcome variables are 'displayed in percentages' this suggests that they aren't originally percentages. Presumably they are counts.  @whuber is suggesting starting instead with a logistic (or multinomial logistic) regression model, for which even conditional normality is not a requirement.

Comment: Thanks for these. However, although I do have the raw counts, the particular research I am carrying out means that I would expect that the raw counts would increase with my predictor variables. Therefore, percentages are giving me a more reliable measure in my analyses.

Comment: As per @whuber... Are you sure this isn't a binomial process?  I would pick a trials count for each record and model it as success and failures. glm binomial supports this. If it isn't binomial in nature, perhaps try inverse hyperbolic sine transformations http://worthwhile.typepad.com/worthwhile_canadian_initi/2011/07/a-rant-on-inverse-hyperbolic-sine-transformations.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've had luck with setting epsilon to half of the smallest non-zero value and replacing all 0 values with epsilon and all 1 values with 1-epsilon. Then apply the logit transformation.

This method keeps the original form of the logit transformation, but allows 1 and 0 to be transformed to values that match the overall shape of the intended transformation (note the black dots in the figure at raw=0 and 1).  In particular, it preserves the quality that 0.5 is transformed to 0, and the rest of the values are symmetric.

On the other hand, adding the smallest non-zero value as described in the paper changes the shape of the curve and destroys the symmetry.

[image: Comparing two methods of ways to adjust the logit transformation to deal with zeros]

Comment: Welcome to our site! This thoughtful, well-illustrated post is a useful contribution.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a go, although I have been experimenting with zero/one inflated beta regression too.

Comment: Is that right that the empirical logit isn't centered at 0?  This equation `log((0.5 + eps)/(1 - 0.5 + eps))` always gives me 0 no matter what eps is.  I also plotted logit vs empirical logit curves and empirical logit is symmetric as well, but the curve is a bit less steep as you get toward the edges for large eps.  Using a smaller eps can correct this, but then the points near 0 and 1 will get increasingly pulled closer to +/- infinity.  Still, it behaves pretty well for values like 1e-3 to 1e-5

Answer (score 2):

One approach, which would solve the problem you are having, is to use a robust regression method on the raw, untransformed values. For example, in R, you could do the following:

```
example = data.frame(outcome = c(0,0,0.3,0.7,1), 
                     predictor = c('left','left','left','right','right'))
m = glm(outcome ~ predictor,example,family=quasibinomial())
summary(m)
```