# Linear regression Vs Logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, linear

I have a time series dataset. The,

X (Independent variable) is time and is denoted as 1,2,3,4,5,6..1000.etc
Y (Dependent variable ) is a percentage scale as 99%, 98.7%, 96%, 91% ...etc. This is a continuous data set.

I have 1000 such data points. The first 700 data points used as training set and rest 300 is used for testing.

I tried to use simple linear regression but when predicting sometimes the prediction is more than 100%. And the case is even worse when I calculated the confidence interval and prediction interval.

So I tried to use logistic regression as there is a boundary ( from 0% to 100%). But logistic regression can take only binary data. I am confused on how to appropriately convert my existing time series data so that I can try how logistic regression on that.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that logistic regression is only for binary response data, which is not applicable here. What you may be wanting to do is simply apply the [logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) transform to the response data (i.e. the $Y$ values) and then use linear regression on the transformed data. Then apply the inverse logit transform to predictions to put them back on the original scale.

However, if you are trying to forecast a time series, simple linear regression may not be the best approach. It may be better to fit a time series model to the data (after applying the logit transform to the response) and use that as a basis for prediction.

Comment: There is also the variance stabilized arcsine square root transformations if $Y$ is a proportion.

Comment: A minor remark is that after such rescaling the MSE error changes significantly (algorithm will pay more attention to 'limit cases'), but this is solvable e.g. by adding weights

Comment: Hello Brent, Thanks for your reply. Can we also logit transform the X (time scale) with Y and then use regression?

Comment: It's not clear why you would want to transform the time scale. You could do it, but unless you have a good reason for doing so, it probably wouldn't be recommended.

Comment: Hey Brent, Thanks again. I tried and it looks good now. But I was wondering on how do we calculate the confidence and prediction intervals the predicted Y's. If we do it after inverse logit then the Y crosses again 100%. Could we do it before logit? If so can you advice me on that procedure?

Comment: Confidence and prediction intervals should be constructed first before the inverse logit; then apply the inverse logit separately to the lower and upper endpoint of the interval.

Comment: What should be done if I want to do log transformation of values that include 0 (zero) for statistical analyses? There are zero values for some days and I need it to be there in the analysis. For example, the zero percentage represent breakdown hours over scheduled production hours of the machine. And this zero percentage is important in calculations

Comment: In this case, one solution is to replace the 0's by a small positive number (similarly in case there are 1's). See this question for a discussion: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109702/empirical-logit-transformation-on-percentage-data.